# ListView Grouping without using IGrouping<TKey, TModel>

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way for me to group my data in a ListView without the collection I use implementing

```
IGrouping<TKey, TModel>
```

I'm using this [VirtualCollection](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample/tree/master/src/Inventory.App/Common/VirtualCollection). When I then implement IGrouping on my ListViewModel and add a CollectionViewSource to my page the VirtualCollection never adds new items when scrolling down. The grouping does work, I can see my ListView headers, but more data never gets added.

So my ideal world would be if I don't have to implement the IGrouping interface and still get the desired result which is grouping my ListView data plus I won't have 2 lists of data, 1 for all the items and 1 for the groups that holds the items.

Answer (score -1):

You could group your data in listview by not implementing `IGrouping<TKey, TModel>`. Please refer to the following sample.

XAML code:

```
<Page
   ..>
   <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs" x:Key="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
   </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind cvs.View,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.GroupStyle >
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace GroupingListView
{
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> persons { get; set; }      
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
            {
                new Person(){name="Tom",job="teacher",age=27},
                new Person(){name="Jack",job="lawyer",age=29},
                new Person(){name="Lily",job="teacher",age=22},
                new Person(){name="Arice",job="doctor",age=23},
                new Person(){name="Ethan",job="teacher",age=22},
                new Person(){name="Kiki",job="lawyer",age=27},
                new Person(){name="Sherry",job="doctor",age=20},
                new Person(){name="Json",job="lawyer",age=26},
                new Person(){name="Jovi",job="doctor",age=23},
                new Person(){name="Seria",job="teacher",age=25},
            };
            var group = from p in persons group p by p.job;
            this.cvs.Source = group;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string job { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using `group by` which returns `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`  - exactly what the OP doesn't want.